# Blender Boolean Modifier issue

Tags: modifiers

So this is one of the weirdest problems i could have had. Whenever i use two shapes different than a cube and another cube (and by that i mean that this combination is the only one that works, none other does), the difference option in boolean modifier is acting... Really strange.
For exemple, i had a cube and a cylinder, the cylinder was supposed to get substracted from the cube...
The problem wasn't an artifact, a terrible result or just a kind of bad geometry. The entire cylinder was added to the geometry of the cube. I thought it might have been substracted at the same time, but no...

I don't even know how this is possible. It works like the union, except the union doesn't work at all, acting like an intersect while the intersect just make everything disappear.

If anyone has already encountered the problem or found an answer deep down at the page 125 of Google, please let me know.

Best regards.

Edit: the image below shows the problem. All the boolean carvers are in Bounds display, so the cylinders you see here are actually the problem i talked about (they are added to the initial mesh)

It only works if the cube is carved by another cube (1st object)

Whether it is a simple cube (2nd, 3rd has one side beveled)

[image]

By the way, it worked fine for long and the problem suddenly appeared.

Comment: Never had a problem with boolean that I didn't anticipate. Could you share a .blend and download the LTS (2.83 official) to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Drop us a screenshot.

Comment: I will download the latest version of blender, I will let you know if my problem keeps happening.